# PDFViewerApplication odoo v 13

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, odoo, odoo-13

How, i can overwrite method handleMouseWheel for PDFViewerApplication in my js file.
This method locate in pdfjs/web/viewer.js
Method looks like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As its external library i think its best add your own version and and load it instead.
Repoint template `pdf_js_lib` to your version of the library or change views that use it.